# GeoCoordinateWatcher StatusChanged event in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps

I am developing an application that tracks my route. When the user starts the application, I want to make sure whether the GPS is enabled or not. So I wrote this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {            
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            Transporter._watcher.StatusChanged += _watcher_StatusChanged;
        }  
void _watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {          
            button1.IsEnabled = false; //appbar buttons
            button2.IsEnabled = false;

        switch (e.Status)
        {

            case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:
                button1.IsEnabled = false;
                button2.IsEnabled = false;
                menuitem1.Text = "searching gps signal...";                    
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                button1.IsEnabled = false;
                button2.IsEnabled = false;
                menuitem1.Text = "no location info";                    
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                button1.IsEnabled = true;                    
                menuitem1.Text = "gps ok";                    
                break;
        }
    }
```

And my problem is, when the user forget to turn on the GPS before starting the application, they have to minimize the app, turn the gps on, and go back to the app. I tried it out, OnNavigatedTo event fires, so as StatusChanged, but nothing happens. 
Why is that happening? It should get to the Initializing Status and then Ready.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for the GPS running, you could use [Geolocator.LocationStatus property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.locationstatus). It's [values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.positionstatus) will tell you if it's initializing, switched off and so on.

So maybe this will help:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (yourGeolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
        {
            // do your stuff for disabled GPS
        }
        else  NotDisabled();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and nothing happens. I think I need something that start searching my location in the background when the OnNavigatedTo fires , and tells the UI, if my location is available, so I can refresh my buttons and the text. Is this doable?

Comment: @DanielT. Check [this simple example](http://1drv.ms/1kbYOGz) on the device - I have tried two scenatios: 1) Location disabled in settings - I get 'disabled' result. Location enabled in settings - I get 'ok' meddage.